# @react-google-maps Marker LatLng throwing error

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm using the `@react-google-maps/api` to build my first react map.. But my latLng literal for position inside the `Marker` is breaking my code. Is this not the same latLng format that I'm using for `center` which works fine? How is my Marker latLng wrong? That seems to be the only required attribute in the [docs](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker) so I'm at a dead end.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import icon1 from '../map/icon1.svg';
import iconDead from '../map/iconDead.svg';

const center = { lat: 51.510228, lng: -0.132992 };
const API = 'xxxx'; 
const containerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '800px'
};

function MyComponent( markers, onToggleOpen ) {

  
  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey={API}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
      >
        <Marker position={ lat: 51.510228, lng: -0.132992 }></Marker>
        <></>
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  )
}
 
export default React.memo(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position property is an object. Hand your lat and lng values like this:

```
<Marker position={{lat: 51.510228, lng: -0.132992}}></Marker>
```